# CORS with Windows Authentication

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication, cors, ntlm

I've run into the CORS issue when doing an xhr request to a different domain (in my case, localhost to another server). An article, [*The CORS*](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/the-cors/), describes the various issues I've run into. I've managed to solve the first two problems, related to both xhr and json.

Now, I receive a 401, as described in 'Problem 3' on the blog. However, I'm using Windows Authentication (via NTLM). What can I do to fix this?  The call to the server is very simple:

```
$.ajax('http://myserver/mymethod', {    
   contentType: 'application/json',
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
})
```

Comment: Can you update the question to include information such as if you're setting any relevant headers such as 'Allow-Access-Control-Origin'. What origins/methods/verbs are allowed. Also, you could include (but scrub confidential details) a fiddler trace. Finally, how you're hosting your web-service (WebApi2 for example). It would help to make answers you get a bit more accurate and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the "withCredentials" flag. Perhaps this will help:

http://brockallen.com/2012/12/15/cors-and-windows-authentication/

Comment: Thanks but actually, I had already tried that  with no luck. I've updated my post accordingly.